# What is the simplest way to test for a null value in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string named ds and need to test only if it **is null or not**. Can I just do the following?

```
if (ds) { }
```

It passes a syntax check so I am wondering what conditions this would test as true.

what does the above code do?

Comment: No, that won't compile at all.

Comment: What do you mean by saying it "passes a syntax check"?

Comment: I think that you should specify in the question that you are trying to find find if the string is null **or empty**, because if you asked for **null only** then *if (ds == null)* is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String.IsNullOrEmpty will check to see if the string is empty or null.

```
if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( ds)) { 
    // String is valid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a different way:

```
if (ds == null)
```

However there are useful methods for assignment operation:

```
MyClass a;
MyClass b = null;
a = b ?? new MyClass();
```

This will assign b to a if b is not null, otherwise will assign new MyClass() to a

So to check if a string is null **(and only null)**

```
if (ds == null)
```

otherwise you can use

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds))
```

or

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ds))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a string you might want to use the `IsNullOrEmpty` method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx

It is, of course, short for

```
result = s == null || s == String.Empty;
```